# Javascript code is working if I am using alert in it otherwise it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest in side javascript code.

I am using jquery-1.7.1.

If I am using alert after XMLHttpRequest then the next code work smoothly but when removing that alert the next statement is not getting value of variable which is initialize inside the XMLHttpRequest block.

Following is the code which I am using

```
var dyn_data='';
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if (xmlhttp) 
{ 
    var query = 'ACTION=test&format=text';
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'sample.php'); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(query); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            var arrayindex=0;

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                dyn_data=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
}
var obj = $.parseJSON(dyn_data);
alert(obj);
var data=obj;
```

If I am commenting alert in above code then it is not working.

I tried following statement at place of alert but it is also not work for me.

```
setTimeout(function(){  }, 5000);
```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous. This means that the `dyn_data` value has not been set before the `$.parseJSON` line is reached. All code which relies on the response should be placed in the `onreadystatechange` handler. Try this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (xmlhttp) { 
    var query = 'ACTION=test&format=text';
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'sample.php'); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xmlhttp.send(query); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        var arrayindex = 0;
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(obj);
            var data = obj;
        }
    }
}
```